# Is the tradition that there was 124,000 prophets attested in the Qu'ran or the Hadith?

Tags: hadith

The main question is already in the headline but I'll repeat it here: Is the tradition that there was 124,000 prophets (before Muhammed pbuh) attested in the Qu'ran or the Hadith? Also, are these to every people or to one specific people?

Comment: Your second question doesn't seem to make sense as we know from the Qur'an that many if not most prophets and messengers where sent to specific people and tribes.

Answer (score 1):

The Hadith mentions 124,000 prophets, most of them not mentioned by name. The Quran mentions 25 prophets by name